# How to get the echoed element in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've a php file that echoes an `<img>` element from a PHP file with `id="uploadedPhoto"`.
After uploading it i have a Jquery script that changes the size of the image on button click. Before this it was working when i was using img as background of a div however now it isn't working.

HTML Code.

```
<div class="mainArea" id="response"> 
    <div class="designer">
        <?php include"shirtBasic.svg" ?>
        <div id="imageDiv"> </div>
    </div>
```

**`<img>` is uploaded in between `id="imageDiv"`**.

PHP Code.

```
if(normal_resize_image($image_res, $image_save_folder, $image_type, $max_image_size, $image_width, $image_height, $jpeg_quality)){

    echo '<div align="center">';        
    echo '<img id="uploadedPhoto" src="'. $new_file_name.'" alt="Resized Image">';
    echo '</div>';  
}
```

JScript.

```
$('#large').click(function(){

        var height = document.getElementById('uploadedPhoto').clientHeight;
        var width = document.getElementById('uploadedPhoto').clientWidth;

        if (height > width) {
            $('#uploadedPhoto').css('height', '115%');
            $('#upoladedPhoto').css('width', '95%');    
        }
        else if (height < width) {
            $('#uploadedPhoto').css('height', '95%');
            $('#uploadedPhoto').css('width', '115%');
        }
        else {
            $('#uploadedPhoto').css('height', '115%');
            $('#uploadedPhoto').css('width', '115%');
        } 

    });

    $('#medium').click(function(){

        var height = document.getElementById('uploadedPhoto').clientHeight;
        var width = document.getElementById('uploadedPhoto').clientWidth;

        if (height > width) {
            $('#uploadedPhoto').css('height', '85%');
            $('#upoladedPhoto').css('width', '70%');    
        }
        else if (height < width) {
            $('#uploadedPhoto').css('height', '70%');
            $('#uploadedPhoto').css('width', '85%');
        }
        else {
            $('#uploadedPhoto').css('height', '85%');
            $('#uploadedPhoto').css('width', '85%');
        }   

    });

    $('#small').click(function(){

        var height = document.getElementById('uploadedPhoto').clientHeight;
        var width = document.getElementById('uploadedPhoto').clientWidth;

        if (height > width) {
            $('#uploadedPhoto').css('height', '65%');
            $('#upoladedPhoto').css('width', '50%');    
        }
        else if (height < width) {
            $('#uploadedPhoto').css('height', '50%');
            $('#uploadedPhoto').css('width', '65%');
        }
        else {
            $('#uploadedPhoto').css('height', '65%');
            $('#uploadedPhoto').css('width', '65%');
        }   
    });

    $('#originalSize').click(function(){

        var height = document.getElementById('uploadedPhoto').clientHeight;
        var width = document.getElementById('uploadedPhoto').clientWidth;

        $('#uploadedPhoto').css('height', height);
        $('#upoladedPhoto').css('width', width);                
    });
```

Can you please find the problem?

Comment: What's your Final HTML that you see in the browser? Do you see the image fine? Your code appears to be fine and should work if theres no typo or something small

Comment: `$('#upoladedPhoto').css('width', '70%');` **upOladed**? really? Copypaste is such copypaste.

Comment: There you go, that's the first typo spotted

Comment: @u_mulder UGHHHHH KILL ME KILL ME NOW

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with DOM structure. I guess your image automatically uses the size of div tag

you use to expand or reduce the size.

So i recommend you to try, fix the size of this div.

Atul